# How to speed up nested loops in python?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have read that we can use map function to speed up for loops. But, in my code I have nested loops and I was wondering if there is anyway to speed up my code using map function or any other method.

```
import copy as cpy
import time

def powerset(s):
    set =[]
    x = len(s)
    for i in range(1 << x):
         set.append([s[j] for j in range(x) if (i & (1 << j))])
    return set

def func1(Num):

    Num_set = range(1, Num + 1)
    A = []
    for i in range(1, Num + 1):
        my_set = cpy.deepcopy(Num_set)
        my_set.remove(i)
        my_subset = list(powerset(my_set))

        for j in range(0, len(my_subset)):
            name = "{r}:{s}".format(r=i, s=list(my_subset[j]))
            A.append(name)
    return A

start = time.time()
N = 10
A = func1(N)
end = time.time()
print("Run time:{t}".format(t=end - start))
```

The runtime of above code for N=10 is:

```
Run time:0.0383169651031
```

But the runtime for N=20 is around two minutes:

```
Run time:101.803981066
```

Any idea for speeding up the nested loop in function func1?

**What this code does**: Consider a number N =3. Function func1, first creates a list Num_set=[1,2,3]. Then for each element of this list say i, it generates all non-empty subsets of set(Num_set without i). For example if i=2, it adds "2,[]","2,[1]","2,[3]","2,[1,3]" to list A.

Many thanks!

Comment: "I have read that we can use map function to speed up for loops." Only in some cases and generally only marginally... Your problem here is inherently your algorithm

Comment: the way to speed up loops in Python, is not to run those loops in Python! By that I mean let a compiled library do the heavy lifting...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga So, it is problem specific and there is not a general way that can be used for all problems?

Comment: @MitchWheat Can you please provide more information? I didn't get what you said.

Comment: What are you doing? Why are you computing the powerset of 1 to (A-1), (A+1) to N for every A in 1 to N?

Comment: @MitchWheat likely not going to help here, just judging by the names of the functions, this is calculating powersets, which will take exponential time.

Comment: true, I was talking more in general....

Comment: Try to vectorise first, eg via a package. If that fails, profile your code. If your numerical calculations are expensive you might find numba helpful.

Comment: No, there is no magical general way to speed up your code. Again in your case, the problem seems to be algorithmic complexity

Comment: @jpp almost certainly not going to help here. The problem is algorithmic complexity, not constant  factors

Comment: @DanD.  I added a description about what my code does.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could at least improve the parts that can:

```
for i in range(1, Num + 1):
    my_set = cpy.deepcopy(Num_set)
    my_set.remove(i)
    my_subset = list(powerset(my_set))

    for j in range(0, len(my_subset)):
        name = "{r}:{s}".format(r=i, s=list(my_subset[j]))
        A.append(name)
```

This removes unneeded copying:

```
for i in range(1, Num + 1):
    # copying and then removing one item is more costly than simply making the list
    my_set = range(1, i) + range(i + 1, Num + 1)

    for s in powerset(my_set):
        name = "{r}:{s}".format(r=i, s=s)
        A.append(name)
```